# sequence of function, what is wrong with my solution?

Tags: calculus, functions, convergence-divergence

**Prove that the following series converges uniformly in $[0,\infty)$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{x+n}$$**

So, I need to prove that for every $x\geq0$ and every $\epsilon > 0 $ the following is true: $$\lim \sup |S(x)-S_n(x)|=0$$

So, I found:
$$\lim \sup |S(x)-S_n(x)| \leq \lim \sup \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{x+k}$$

but the latter doesn't converge to zero... how may I solve this?

Comment: you can proceed as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857417/156150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternating series test clearly applies here for any given $x$: we have a series whose terms alternate in sign, but the absolute values of whom tend to $0$ monotonically. I'm guessing you probably are aware that the function converges, but there's a bit extra to the conclusion alternating series test that is not so well known: the remainder of the series is less than or equal to the absolute value of the next term. That is,

$$\left|S(x) - S_n(x)\right| \le \frac{1}{x + n + 1} \le \frac{1}{n + 1},$$

when $x \ge 0$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$S(x)$ is between $S_n(x)$ and $S_{n+1}(x)$  as this is an alternating series with terms reducing in absolute value to $0$, so  $$\left|S(x) - S_n(x)\right| \le \left|S_{n+1}(x)- S_n(x)\right| = \frac{1}{x+n} \le \frac{1}{n}$$